# Writing Qsettings of Qcombobox to a file without closing Widget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qcombobox, qsettings

Having a `Qtablewidget` runs up as start widget and having `Con` widget imported to `QTableWidget`. From `QCombobox` wishs to save and restore to a file with path to a directory. Each widgets and layouts work, the issue is with QCombobox Saving function. Thinks to start and run app, when value of Qcombobox is changed then `self.writeSettings` fuction should run and write? but it does not work. Wonder what is it wrong here? Any help appreciate. I reproduce to minimal and productive code below.

```
class CON(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, rowTable, parent=None):
        super(CON, self).__init__(parent)  
        self.rowtable = rowTable
        self.combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.combo.addItems(["15","20","25","30","37","45","50","55",
                       "60","67","75","85","95","105"])

        ------------------------------------

       self.combo.activated.connect(self.setdata)
       self.readSettings()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def setdata(self, index):
        self.writeSettings()


    def readSettings(self):
        settings = QtCore.QSettings('files/con{}.ini'.format(self.rowtable) ,QtCore.QSettings.IniFormat)
        settings.beginGroup("Con")
        self.combo.setCurrentIndex(settings.value("Conoption", 4))
        settings.endGroup()

    def writeSettings(self):
        settings = QtCore.QSettings('files/con{}.ini'.format(self.rowtable) ,QtCore.QSettings.IniFormat)
        settings.beginGroup("Con")
        settings.setValue("Conoption",self.combo.currentIndex())
        settings.endGroup()
```

Comment: I don't understand you, besides the code you provide is not an MRE

Comment: I understand it is not clear enough. I need to reproduce a workable and very short code, but first tomorrow and update and let you know, when code will update.

Comment: I have patched your code and I could execute it so I got a problem that I indicated in my answer. On the other hand it is annoying that you are aware of the lack of clarity of your question and do not strive to improve it. What SO requires is that you take the time to post the best possible question as we strive to help you.

Comment: This is very long code, I tried to shorten so much possible, so your guys maybe catch the error quickly. when I feel, information is not enough, then I do really take time to reproduce the problem. that is why I mention in my previous post to update code tomorrow. Much presentation as possible.

Comment: First when I run the code, does not give me any error, and look into my files to see writeSetting has indeed created any file with con0 etc... there is not such files. But I come with update soon... Thanks for reply.

Comment: Then you should post your question tomorrow when you had a better question. It is only a tip: If your project is large and you are going to add a new functionality then do not add it directly but you should create another small project focused on that functionality, test it and then when it is stable just try to join it to the main project, so if you have Some problem you just have to publish the small project as MRE, on the other hand you do not break your final project, although it seems to invest more time in the short term this will save you time in the long term.

Comment: Have you executed it in the CMD or in an IDE? Many IDEs do not handle errors correctly.

Comment: I agree and I have indeed taken your advice from my previous posts and implement it and really benefits me and still do the same procedure.

Comment: Indeed both of them, and no error I get, strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only error I get is the value read is interpreted as str, so to avoid this you must indicate the type of reading:

```
settings.beginGroup("Con")
self.combo.setCurrentIndex(settings.value("Conoption", 4, int))
settings.endGroup()
```

Comment: I mark your answer as correct, I do cut code into small pieces and get only str error. No need to upload addition update, Thanks.